# Reverse FK constraint in Postgresql 9.0?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, postgresql

I know I can setup a FK constraint to make sure Table1.ColA exists in
Table2.Key, however what if I want to do the reverse?

I want to ensure Table1.ColA does NOT exist in Table2.Key..  Can I do
this with any sort of CHECK constraint, trigger, custom function, etc?
 Thanks!

EDIT:

Let's say I have a table called "Names" :

```
1 Michael
2 David
3 William
```

Now I have a table called "Nicknames":

```
Mike -> 1
Mikey -> 1
Dave -> 2
Bill -> 3
Will -> 3
```

I want to make sure no one adds the row "Michael" to "Nicknames" since it already exists in "Names".

Comment: Can you give bigger picture please? I suspect there are other ways to do this. For example, do you want to allow one row only in one of 3 child tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Standard SQL you can use `CREATE ASSERTION` but PostgreSQL doesn't support it. You can fake it in triggers on both tables (e.g. `UNION` the two tables, `GROUP BY` names and test `COUNT(*) > 1` or perhaps just test that the logical `inserted` table values do not appear in the other table) or otherwise procedural code.

You can 'design away' the problem by using one table and an explicit subtype and use a conventional `UNIQUE` constraint, as suggested by @gbn.

Comment: Excellent, it sounds like a trigger is my best bet then..  Thanks!

Comment: Ah, one of those theoretical standards..  Like HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using one table with

- "name type" (primar, nick name)
- "nickname of" which is a self FK

As I understand it, you have a list of names that should be unique.

This will remove the need for any code to maintain the "not FK"

Comment: This would definitely work, but the primary table has a very complicated schema, constraints of its own, indexes, and dozens of functions and views reading it.  Putting extra rows in there with mostly null values that just point to another row in the same table would be a change I'm not comfortable with.

Comment: @Mike Christensen: write code then: you^ll have to use a trigger. You can split the names off (name, nametype) and keep the complex details in another table with PK of (name, nametype) with FK to simple table, check on nametype = 1 (for primary)